# My JSON save and load function is not working

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am writing a simple function to save a twitter search as a JSON, and then load the results. The save function seems to work but the load one doesn't. The error I receive is:

"UnsupportedOperation: not readable"

Can you please advise what the issue might be in my script?

```
import io

def save_json(filename, data):
    with open('tweet2.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
        json.dump(data, file, ensure_ascii = False)

def load_json(filename):
    with open('tweet2.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as file:
        return json.load(file)

#sample usage

q = 'Test'

results  = twitter_search(twitter_api, q, max_results = 10)

save_json = (q, results)
results = load_json(q)

print(json.dumps(results, indent = 1, ensure_ascii = False))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `"w"` you won't be able to read the file so you need to use `"r"` (Opens a file for reading only.)

```
open("tweet2.json","r")
```